# Am I doing this Time complexity for a while loop right?

Tags: java, while-loop, time-complexity

This is what I calculated, I find myself struggling when It comes to the while loops. Did I do this correctly?

```
                        //Cost      Times
    count = 0;          //c1        //1
    int j = N;          //c2        //1
    while(j>1) {        //c3        //log2(N) + 1
        count += 1;     //c4        //log2(N)
        j= j/2;         //c5        //log2(N)
    }//T(N) = c1*1 + c2*1 + c3* (log2(N)+1) + c4 * log2(N) + c5*log2(N) =
    //O(log2(N))
```

Please help me in anyway possible.

Comment: The time complexity of the while loop is `O(log2(n))`. Not sure about your `T(N)` equation: I don’t think you include setup and assignments unless they have non-constant time complexities and pertain to the time complexity being assessed. But I haven’t done mathematical big-O analysis in quite some time.

Comment: Your thinking is too complicated. Write N as a binary number, composed of digits 0 and 1. j=j/2 is just shifting right. When the last digit 1 has vanished, the task is done. It's as easy as that.

Comment: Just nitpicking: as the length of an int is limited, the complexity is O(1). ;-)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's great to have you here. However, your question might benefit from some improvements. Could you provide more context and be more specific about your issue? This will help you get better responses. Please read following guide: [How To: Write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Afterwards [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) your post and improve it. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your analysis is correct.

Keep in mind though, when doing complexity analysis, normally you need a data set in order to establish a relationship between the data that is fed into an algorithm and the time needed to process it.

For example, if your input is an array, the time complexity will indeed be O(logN) where N = the size of the array. (The logarithm base is typically ommited because it is assumed to be 2 in CS)